# Extract Data with Certain Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some helps. Pls refer to the below image:-

[image]

How can I do so via SQL ?

[image]

by using the following SQL:-

```
Select Size, Grade, sum(Qty) Qty, Price, sum(Qty*Price) Value
From TableA
Left outer join 
TableB 
on a.Size=b.Size and a.Grade=b.Grade
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I hv edited the above by adding what I hv done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
WITH agg_cte AS
(
  SELECT size, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN grade = '1' THEN qty END) qty1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN grade = '2' THEN qty END) qty2
    FROM tableb
   GROUP BY size
), totals AS 
(
  SELECT size, qty1, 
         CASE WHEN qty2 > qty1 * 0.2 THEN qty1 * 0.2 ELSE qty2 END qty2,
         CASE WHEN qty2 > qty1 * 0.2 THEN qty2 - qty1 * 0.2 ELSE 0 END qty2e
    FROM agg_cte
)
SELECT p.size, p.grade, 
       CASE p.grade WHEN '1'  THEN qty1
                    WHEN '2'  THEN qty2
                    WHEN '2E' THEN qty2e
       END qty,
       p.price,
       CASE p.grade WHEN '1'  THEN qty1
                    WHEN '2'  THEN qty2
                    WHEN '2E' THEN qty2e
       END * p.price value
FROM TableA p JOIN totals t
    ON p.size = t.size
```

Output:

```
|  SIZE | GRADE | QTY | PRICE | VALUE |
|-------|-------|-----|-------|-------|
| 10/12 |     1 |   5 |  2.39 | 11.95 |
| 10/12 |     2 |   1 |  1.79 |  1.79 |
| 10/12 |    2E |   3 |  1.55 |  4.65 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62453/2)** demo